# Part of a celery task not being executed

Tags: python, django, logging, celery, django-celery

Code:

```
    @task
    def task():
        time.sleep(10)
        a=run() #run is a long running function with string as output
        logger.critical(a)
        logger.critical("after running celery")
        return

    def view()
        logger.critical("before running celery")
        task.delay()
        return http response
```

Expected Output in log file:

```
    before running celery
    a(string stored in variable a)
    after running celery
```

Actual Output in log file:

```
    before running celery(@time t)
    after running celery (@time t+10sec)
```

The output of the long running function which is stored in variable a is not being logged. I even tried in the following way in the above mentioned task instead of `logger.critical(a)`

```
    try:
        a=run() #long running function
        logger.critical("success")
    except:
        logger.critical("failure")
```

Still I got the same output neither success nor failure was logged.

*Questions*

1. Can someone please tell me why the function is not being executed and why I am not even getting an error?
2. I am using a django-redis-celery setup so is it possible to cache the result of the function and display it onto a html page?

Comment: What version of celery are you using? Second, have you walked through [First steps with Django](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html)? They show how to use the `@shared_task` decorator.

Comment: @Jarad I use celery of version 5.1.2 . Yes I have gone through the mentioned doc but the problem is I am using celery in a custom django based project called **nautobot** in which there is only one tag available for use called **@nautobot_task** and it  is equivalent to **shared task**.  It has no app instance and I use that decorator directly so I think it should serve the purpose but I am facing the above mentioned problem.  Can you please tell me  the reason why it is skipping the function then based on that I will try to find a solution.